# Inserting to Oracle Synonym

Tags: database, oracle, synonym

If I have a Synonym of a table of another Schema, can I make an insert into the Synonym?
If so, will it also affect the original table?

Comment: A synonym is just a pointer to an object. So you can treat it in your SQL code like a local object and any DML operation executed against it will be performed on the pointed object.

Answer (score 5):

A synonym is not a "real" object, but simply a pointer to an object; so, whatever you do on a synonym, you are doing on the referred object.

You can access a table in a different schema by explicitly writing the schema:

```
SQL> select count(1) from sys.sys_table;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(1) from sys_table;
select count(1) from sys_table
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Create a synonym

```
SQL> create synonym my_synonym for sys.sys_table;

Synonym created.
```

Then you can use the synonym to access to the table:

```
SQL> select count(1) from my_synonym;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0
```

But you still can't directly access the table:

```
SQL> select count(1) from sys_table;
select count(1) from sys_table
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

You can insert into your table, using the synonym

```
SQL> insert into my_synonym values (1);

1 row created.
```

... or using `schema.table`:

```
SQL> insert into sys.sys_table values (2);

1 row created.
```

No matter how you do, all the rows are inserted:

```
SQL> select count(1) from sys.sys_table;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         2

SQL> select count(1) from my_synonym;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         2
```

If you drop the synonym

```
SQL> drop synonym my_synonym;

Synonym dropped.
```

You need to use schema.table, and the data and the table still remain:

```
SQL> select count(1) from sys.sys_table;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         2
```

but, of course, you can no longer use the synonym

```
SQL> select count(1) from my_synonym;

    select count(1) from my_synonym
                         *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```